# NODE JS Api working from Postman results in timeout from App

Tags: android, node.js, express, salesforce

I have a Node js API written in express framework. 
I am sending some data over all my api does is calculate number of Packages to make For example :- 100/10 = 10 packages to make.
Loops and creates packages in sales force and firebase one by one.

Works fine from postman.

Problem:

When i try to hit the api from my app it works fine when the package count is <= 10. when > 10 ,Lets say 25 it calculates packages and run a loop of 25 and creates packages,crashes after 11th iteration and restarts the route, calculate again 25 packages to create and resulting in "Over weight error".

1- thought it was from android error may be i was hitting two request one after an other ( this was not the case ).
2- Tried sending header "Connection" "Keep-Alive" ( as Postman does ) not working.
3- tried to put up the timeout in the below code it did not work either ( tried variations of time out like 0, 50,000 ms )

```
else {
            console.log('=====By Item=============');
            const supplierFinishedGood = {
                Name: parentBatchDoc['itemName'],
                Supplier_Product__c: parentBatchDoc['id'],
                Package_Size__c: 'a090S000001ZQ5kQAG', // Hard coded PackageSize in 'Gram' as per SALESFORCE
                On_Hand_Amount__c: childBatch['batchWeight']
            }
            console.log('=====By Item============= 2');
            const SupplierFinishedProductID = await createSupplierFinishedProduct(supplierFinishedGood, bearerToken);
            const Quantity_Packaged__c = Math.floor((childBatch['batchWeight'] - childBatch['batchTestAmount']) / noOfPackage);
            console.log('=====By Item============= 3');
            //console.log('Quantity_Packaged__c ==== Remaining_Grams_Available_for_Packaging__c', Quantity_Packaged__c, parentBatchSalesforce['Remaining_Grams_Available_for_Packaging__c']);

            for (let index = 0; index < noOfPackage; index++) {
                if (parentBatchSalesforce['Remaining_Grams_Available_for_Packaging__c'] > Quantity_Packaged__c) {
                    let package = {
                        Batch__c: childId,
                        Product__c: SupplierFinishedProductID,
                        Inventory_Location__c: 'a030S000003x7M7QAI', //Hard coded InventoryLocation 'StorageFinished' as per SALESFORCE
                        Number_Of_Items__c: noOfItemInPackage,
                        Quantity_Packaged__c: Quantity_Packaged__c,
                        Date_Packaged__c: datePackaged,
                        Expiration_Date__c: expirationDate
                    };
                    console.log('Before creating apcaktge ', index);
                    const packageID = await createPackage(package, bearerToken);
                    console.log('After creating package ', index, parentBatchSalesforce['Remaining_Grams_Available_for_Packaging__c']);

                    package['parentBatchId'] = parentId;
                    package['status'] = 'Ready to checkout';
                    package['uid'] = packageID;
                    const packageFBResponse = await db.collection('packages').doc(packageID).set(package, { merge: true });
                    reponseBody.push(packageID);
                } else {
                    console.log('======Over 
          Weight====');
}

Above code is what produces the error. 
There is a If condition before this it works fine i have tested it 
as it has some other scenario.

End result should not be a timeout error.
API should create all the packages and return the result.
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found a workaround. I am Playing around batch status and my code returns me the IDs which i need and packages are created.

This is not the ultimated best solution it is a work around. i am still open to know what the actual problem is.

```
parentBatchDoc['childBatches'][childId]['batchStatus'] = "In Processing";
            const parentBatchDocResponse = await db.collection('batches').doc(parentId).set(parentBatchDoc, { merge: true });

if(parentBatchDoc['childBatches'][childId]['batchStatus'] !== "In Processing"){
    ===================Rest of the case of =======================
}
```